# PyCharm starts so many python process and consumes CPU and memory resources

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, progress

#### My computer environment:

- Windows 10 : 1709
- PyCharm 2017.3.3 *64
- The default python environment: `D:\softEnvDown\Anaconda2\Scripts\python.exe`

#### When I use PyCharm to open the project, here is what happens:

1. `querying generate skeletons` or something related is shown. When I see these words, I know my computer will crash.
2. When the `indexing` is finished, PyCharm will launch many Python processes.

[image: processes]

The picture shows the 47 process, but I can't interrupt them.

#### I tried:

- rename `.PyCharm2017.3` and open PyCharm, choose `not import settings` (failed)
- uninstall, install, then import the old settings (failed)
- uninstall, install, choose `not import settings` (pass)

But I don't want to uninstall install so frequently.

Comment: "when I see these words, I know my computer will be boom"

Comment: use jupyter notebook.

Comment: @CodeHunter how can that possibly help OP with this issue? PyCharm (or any decent IDE) is hardly comparable to just using a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: me too am facing this problem @mtianyan , did you slove it ?

Comment: I am facing this problem now.